Proof : intersection of sets in $\mathfrak{M}$ is in class $\mathfrak{M}$
Let $\mu^*:[0,\infty]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an outer measure (i.e. $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu^*(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu^*(A_i)$), and let the class $\mathfrak{M}$ be
$$
\mathfrak{M} = \{A \subset X \: : \: \forall E \subset X \, , \, \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A)+\mu^*(E \cap A^c) \}
$$
I want to prove that if $A \, , \, B \in \mathfrak{M}$, then $A \cap B \in \mathfrak{M}$.
For that it is enough to check that
$$\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A \cap B)+\mu^*(E \cap (A \cap B)^c)$$
where $E = (E \cap A \cap B) \cup (E \cap (A \cap B)^c)$, so as $\mu^*$ is an outer measure it follows
$$\mu^*(E) \leq \mu^*(E \cap A \cap B)+\mu^*(E \cap (A \cap B)^c)$$
I'm having bigger problems trying to proof the other inequality:
$$\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap A \cap B)+\mu^*(E \cap (A \cap B)^c) 
            = \mu^*(E \cap A \cap B)+\mu^*((E\cap A^c) \cup  (E\cap B^c))$$
I'll really appreciate any hint you can share with me.
Thanks in advance. Best regards!

The key is to use the fact that both $A$ and $B$ are measurable.
The measurability of $B$ implies
$$ (1)\quad \mu^* (E' ) \ge \mu^*(E' \cap B) + \mu^*(E'\cap B^c).$$
Use $E' = E \cap A$ in (1) to obtain
$$(1') \quad \mu^*(E \cap A)=  \mu^*(E \cap (A\cap B)) + \mu^*(E \cap A \cap B^c).$$
and use $E' = E \cap A^c$ to obtain
$$(1'') \quad \mu^*(E \cap A^c) = \mu*(E \cap A^c \cap B) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c \cap B^c).$$
Use the measurability of $A$ in adding  (1') and (1'') to obtain
\begin{align*} \mu^*(E) & = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c) \\
 & = \mu^*(E \cap (A \cap B)) + \underset{(*)}{\underbrace{\mu^*(E \cap A \cap B^c) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c \cap B) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c \cap B^c)}}.\end{align*}
Since
$$(A\cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c) = (A \cap B^c) \cup A^c = A^c \cup B^c = (A\cap B)^c,$$
the subadditivity of $\mu^*$ gives that $(*)\ge \mu^*(E \cap (A\cap B)^c)$, and the result follows.

Just beat me +1
